# Angular: How can I test component which uses 'getCurrentNavigation'?

Tags: angular, testing

Angular9

I want to test component using jasmine/karma.
But I cannot find the way to write test on component which has routing parameter ( using `getCurrentNavigation` ).

actual component is as below

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

export class myComponent implements OnInit {
  // parameters from previous page
  param1: param1model;
  param2: param2model;
  param3: param3model;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
     ....
  ) {
    if (this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data != undefined) {
      this.param1 = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data.aaa;
      this.param2 = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data.bbb;
      this.param3 = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.data.ccc;
    }
  }
```

and current test code is

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { myComponent } from './myComponent';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

describe('myComponent', () => {
  let component: myComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;
  let router: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [myComponent],

    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
});
```

If I run test, I got

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'extras' of null

And I know it should shows up because this `myComponent` must receive params (param1,param2,param3).

But I don't know how I can receive these params.
On Angular official document, I couldn't find any guides for such case.

I appreciate it if someone would share knowledge to me

Answer (score 0):

Add a spy for this function with mock response

```
spyOn(router, 'getCurrentNavigation').and.returnValue(return something here);
// check what real function returns line 

/*something like this
{extras:{
   state:{
         data: 3
         }
     }
}*/
```

Now it should not give this error

Comment: in this case, I got error. 

`missing the following properties from type 'Navigation': id, initialUrl, extractedUrl, trigger, previousNavigation`
  

Is this because of  `let router: jasmine.SpyObj<Router>;`?